# How to sort a guava table by row natural order and column insertion order

Tags: java, sorting, guava

I have started using guava table package in Java - I am trying to create a table where the rows are sorted by natural order and the columns by the insertion order (so it is a "mix" of TreeMap for the rows and "linkedhashmap" for the columns).

HashBasedTable does not seem to sort anything
TreeTable sorts on both rows and columns -

So here I am looking for the hybrid version.

Answer (score 5):

You can create your own `Table` implementation by using [`Tables.newCustomTable()`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Tables.html#newCustomTable(java.util.Map,%20com.google.common.base.Supplier)) and specifying both the row-holding `Map` and a factory for the row `Map`s.

Comment: Cool, so in this case you'd want a `newCustomTable(new TreeMap<>(), LinkedHashMap::new)`.